# How to multiply nvarchar values to decimal in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written this code

Qty = 5
Rate = 50.10

```
SELECT cast(convert(decimal, qty)+ convert(decimal, rate) as decimal)
FROM product where code='P0001'
```

Result = 250 it should be 250.50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes as

```
SELECT cast(convert(decimal(18,2), qty)+ convert(decimal(18,2), rate) as decimal(18,2))
FROM product where code='P0001'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @QTY VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @RATE VARCHAR(10)
SET @QTY = 5 
SET @RATE = 50.10

SELECT @QTY,@RATE 

SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), @QTY) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), @RATE) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```